# BLAS and LAPACK libraries required for compiling

Tags: c, ubuntu, octave, autotools, configure

I recently downloaded the latest stable release of Gnu Octave, and was attempting to build and install it on my machine (Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS 64bit).

When I run ./configure, I got this error message:

```
configure: error: You are required to have BLAS and LAPACK libraries
```

Does anyone know Where do I obtain these libraries from?

Comment: http://webappl.blogspot.com/2010/07/installing-lapack-on-ubuntu.html?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to run this

```
apt-get install libblas-dev libatlas-dev liblapack-dev
```

All libraries, required by octave package in ubuntu are listed here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/octave3.2 and to build new octave you need `-dev` packages of some listed libs.

The octave in ubuntu configured in rather maximal way - many optional parts of octave are turned on, and this leads to big list of libraries required.

To get most development (`-dev`) packages required by octave you can run:

```
apt-get install octave3.2-headers
```

which installs `-dev`-like package http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/octave3.2-headers of octave itself. This package depends on minimal `-dev` set and they will be installed after this command.

Comment: Thanks. All I needed was to install octave3.2-headers (and tex), and I got the build/install to wor. Incidentally libatlas-dev package does not exist. But like I said, all I needed was the second apt-get command (and also text package).

Comment: `libatlas-dev` was optional part of the first command and in can be in universe/multiverse - the extended package repository for ubuntu.

Comment: I had the same problem with scipy and this fixed my problem. Adding this comment to add the keyword scipy to this page.

Comment: The packages required on my Ubuntu 18.10 system were:
libblas-dev
libatlas-base-dev
liblapack-dev