# Installing BioConductor in Linux

Tags: r, rstudio, bioconductor

I know this has been asked a number of times but I cant figure out the answer from the answers here on StackOverflow or on the BioConductor install page [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/install/). I have installed and updated R to the latest 3.1.3 version which is explicitly stated to work with BioConductor 3.0 on the install page.

I then installed BioConductor and made sure everything was up to date using the following commands:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(ask=FALSE)
biocLite("BiocUpgrade")
```

Everything up to this point works just fine, but then when I go to install any of the BioConductor packages using, for example:

```
biocLite(c("flowCore"))
```

I will get a handful of errors like the following:

```
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
```

My understanding is that this error is indicative of a version mismatch between R and the package and yet it sounds like everything from BioConductor should work with the R version 3.1.3.

When I try to install the the packages listed in the errors manually using, for example:

```
install.packages("robustbase", dependencies=TRUE)
```

And I will get the same type of error as above with the non-zero exit status.

Does anybody know the best way of getting around this? I assume I don't need to downgrade to a previous version of R or anything but I'm really not sure what to do at this point. Thanks.

As requested in the comments below, the full output of the install of a package flowCore using the following code is below:

```
biocLite(c("flowCore"))
```

Output:

```
    BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.2), R version 3.1.3.
Installing package(s) 'flowCore'
also installing the dependencies ‘robustbase’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘cluster’, ‘pcaPP’, ‘rrcov’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/robustbase_0.92-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3144393 bytes (3.0 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3.0 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 155092 bytes (151 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 151 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cluster_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 280102 bytes (273 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 273 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pcaPP_1.9-60.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 191565 bytes (187 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 187 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rrcov_1.3-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 992215 bytes (968 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 968 KB

trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc/src/contrib/flowCore_1.32.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8962871 bytes (8.5 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 8.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘robustbase’ ...
** package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c eigen.f -o eigen.o
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [eigen.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustbase’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/robustbase’
* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [mvt.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/mvtnorm’
* installing *source* package ‘cluster’ ...
** package ‘cluster’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c clara.c -o clara.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c daisy.f -o daisy.o
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [daisy.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cluster’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/cluster’
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘pcaPP’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/pcaPP’
ERROR: dependencies ‘robustbase’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘cluster’, ‘pcaPP’ are not available for package ‘rrcov’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rrcov’
ERROR: dependency ‘rrcov’ is not available for package ‘flowCore’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/flowCore’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpB8elmi/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘cluster’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘pcaPP’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘rrcov’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘flowCore’ had non-zero exit status
```

So I installed gfortran and still get similar errors, though it does appear to get a little further (looks like a problem with llapack and lblas but I'm not sure what those are, I don't find them with apt-cache search:

```
> biocLite(c("flowCore"))
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.2), R version 3.1.3.
Installing package(s) 'flowCore'
also installing the dependencies ‘robustbase’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘cluster’, ‘pcaPP’, ‘rrcov’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/robustbase_0.92-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3144393 bytes (3.0 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3.0 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.0-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 155092 bytes (151 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 151 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cluster_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 280102 bytes (273 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 273 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pcaPP_1.9-60.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 191565 bytes (187 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 187 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rrcov_1.3-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 992215 bytes (968 KB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 968 KB

trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc/src/contrib/flowCore_1.32.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8962871 bytes (8.5 MB)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 8.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘robustbase’ ...
** package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c eigen.f -o eigen.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c lmrob.c -o lmrob.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c mc.c -o mc.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c monitor.c -o monitor.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c qn_sn.c -o qn_sn.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c rf-common.f -o rf-common.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c rffastmcd.f -o rffastmcd.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c rfltsreg.f -o rfltsreg.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c rllarsbi.f -o rllarsbi.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rob-utils.c -o rob-utils.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rowMedians.c -o rowMedians.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c wgt_himed.c -o wgt_himed.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o robustbase.so R-rng4ftn.o eigen.o init.o lmrob.o mc.o monitor.o qn_sn.o rf-common.o rffastmcd.o rfltsreg.o rllarsbi.o rob-utils.o rowMedians.o wgt_himed.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [robustbase.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustbase’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/robustbase’
* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c mvtnorm-init.c -o mvtnorm-init.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c tvpack.f -o tvpack.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o mvtnorm.so C_FORTRAN_interface.o miwa.o mvt.o mvtnorm-init.o tvpack.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/mvtnorm/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (mvtnorm)
* installing *source* package ‘cluster’ ...
** package ‘cluster’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c clara.c -o clara.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c daisy.f -o daisy.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c dysta.f -o dysta.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fanny.c -o fanny.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c mona.f -o mona.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c pam.c -o pam.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c sildist.c -o sildist.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c spannel.c -o spannel.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c twins.c -o twins.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o cluster.so clara.o daisy.o dysta.o fanny.o init.o mona.o pam.o sildist.o spannel.o twins.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/cluster/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (cluster)
* installing *source* package ‘pcaPP’ ...
** package ‘pcaPP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -DR_PACKAGE_FILE     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c L1Median_HoCr.cpp -o L1Median_HoCr.o
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
make: *** [L1Median_HoCr.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pcaPP’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/pcaPP’
ERROR: dependencies ‘robustbase’, ‘pcaPP’ are not available for package ‘rrcov’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rrcov’
ERROR: dependency ‘rrcov’ is not available for package ‘flowCore’
* removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/flowCore’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpB8elmi/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘pcaPP’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘rrcov’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘flowCore’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `robustbase` is not a Bioc packages. Did you first do `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)` after updating R.

Comment: True it is not a Bioc package. And yes I did update all packages as well.

Comment: Try to find dependencies for each cran package, download the source code ".tar.gz" file and install it one by one using install.packages("pkg-name", repos = NULL, type = "source"). When you do this, document the steps in a R script  and save those source codes some where for future purpose

Comment: You can do the same for bioconductor packages by downloading the source and installing them individually. You just have to make sure the order of dependencies follows properly, so install error don't pops up.

Comment: bioconductor package source code can be obtained from each bioconductor package web repository

Comment: some packages needs to be compiled using a c compiler. so if you are working on windows, RTools has all things necessary for compiling a package on windows

Comment: Usually the problem is that some underlying system dependency is not met. This requires that you isolate your installation to the FIRST package that fails to install, and then look for the FIRST error message generated by R during the installation. Update your question with the complete output of biocLite("robustbase"). Don't bother downloading the source tar balls as suggested by @Sathish, you're already installing from source.

Comment: robustbase is from R not bioconductor do you mean give the full error for biocLite(c("flowCore"))? If so I will add that in a minute.

Comment: It's saying you need to install gfortran.

Comment: I just installed gfortran and the install does progress a bit further but still a lot of errors.

Comment: before installing those R packages, check whether gfortran is in your path. For example: echo $PATH should output the values for PATH variable. If you don't find it there,you need to export gfortran path by editing .bashrc or bash profile file. This assumes that your default shell is bash. Usually opening a new bash terminal or logging out and logging in should allow the editing bash files to take effect, but it is good to have the system rebooted, so you work on a fresh one.

Comment: llapack and lblas are libraries for lapack and blas linear algebra routines. You can google lapack and blas to learn more. Basically, these routines help your R program run faster and they are optimized for handling data structures of linear algebra.

Comment: Try this answer to install lapack and blas routines. I assume you are on a debian based distribution - Eg: Ubuntu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961340/blas-and-lapack-libraries-required-for-compiling

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505249) (you don't say which Linux flavour you are using but since you mentioned apt-cache I'm assuming this is relevant although the answer is several years old) the required packages to install LAPACK and BLAS are

```
libblas3gf
libblas-doc
libblas-dev

liblapack3gf
liblapack-doc
liblapack-dev
```

However, I was under the impression that R ships with its own version of these libraries so it may just be a matter of setting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly.

Also note that you seem to be missing *g++* as well.